# How to override Transaction service timeout value in WAS Console by code?

Tags: spring, transactions, timeout, websphere, transactionmanager

In my `xml` file, I have something as follow:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"
        p:defaultTimeout="60" />

<bean id="sharedTransactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </constructor-arg>  
      <property name="isolationLevelName" value="${sharedTransactionTemplate.isolationlevel:ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED}"/>
      <property name="timeout" value="60"/>
    </bean>
```

With the value `60`, my program will hit timeout if the response from db taking more than 60 seconds. This is correct and also what I expected.

And I found that there is some transaction time out value setting in WAS Console as well:

```
Server --> WebSphere application servers --> my server
Under Container Settings --> click on Container Services --> Transaction service
```

Inside Transaction service page, there is a value call "Total transaction lifetime timeout ". I set the value to 80.

In my application, I have a part that will trigger `Spring SimpleJobLauncher` to run a spring batch in my application. In my Spring batch, I have some for loop which is write some data in log file, and it does not have any interaction with DB.

I found that, my for loop will not hit the 60 seconds time out after 60 seconds. It will only hit the 80 seconds time out. I believe that it is because of it didn't call db.

My code is something as follow:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sharedTransactionTemplate")
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

transactionTemplate.execute( new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult( ) {

                        // In here I trigger the spring batch
                    } );
```

I would like to edit this value to for example 70 seconds base on code in xml or any way. I do not want to edit it in WAS Console because I still want other method still using the 80 seconds.

Any ideas?

Here is what my spring batch doing:

1. Call db, update something. (done with no error)
2. reader, read data from db. (done with no error)
3. Before write, i got some for loop which is not call db. --> hit timeout here, I found that the timeout value is the value that set in WAS Console, instead of the value set in xml.
4. and so on...

I actually want to do something that I can code in xml, so that this spring batch can use my own value set in xml. SO that my step 3 can use my own value.

Additional question, are these following class only applicable for transaction that involve connection to database?

```
class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"
class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me from the info you've provided why you are executing your Spring Batch job transactionally, you may want to consider whether you need to.  Although not a duplicate, this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758413/overwriting-transaction-timeout-set-by-websphere) in which you can see one possible solution is to start a UserTransaction for your spring batch job which you can control the timeout.  As pointed out in that answer and subsequent comments, there are some limitations and considerations about using this method.